# Where can I travel using an Italian-issued refugee residence permit?

Tags: visas, refugees, italian-residents, schengen-visas

I am a Pakistani national and I have refugee status in Italy and an Italian-issued refugee residence permit which is valid for 5 years. I have also been issued a refugee passport.

Where am I able to travel using these documents, and without having to obtain a visa. Am I limited to Europe, or can I go to non-European countries?

Comment: @MichaelHampton "can I go to non-European countries with my refugee travel document without needing a visa" is not the same as "can I travel in the EU with my residence permit."

Comment: @phoog The alternative is I could copy and paste the answer here. This probably isn't a good idea...

Comment: @MichaelHampton but that answer doesn't answer this question.

Comment: @phoog That answer _exactly_ answers this question, completely and in full.

Comment: @MichaelHampton you seem so sure of that, but it's not correct. There is st last one country for which the refugee travel document allows a visa exemption but the Schengen residence permit does not.

Comment: @phoog I'm very frequently wrong, and I would certainly welcome seeing any new information. But your comments aren't very useful so far. Please try to be constructive in future.